# Error in x[["translations"]] : object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable when using translate R package

Tags: r, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Translator API to translate the following dataset into English, using the following function from the translateR library:

`Test <- ("草")`

`microsoftTranslate(Test, api.key = 'my api key', source.lang = 'zh-Hans', target.lang = 'en')`

However, I keep getting the following error:

Error in x[["translations"]] :
object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable

I've searched Stack Overflow and the Web, but couldn't seem to find similar issues in this context or clear discussion on the topic. Seem to have found indication that this could be due to parsing issue, have since tried different languages in Roman script, but the same error prevails. I'll have several thousand strings to translate across multiple languages. Grateful for any kind help. Thanks.